# Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google Calendar Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to run the [Calendar App Engine Sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-appengine-sample/instructions.html). But after running on `http://localhost:8888`, it produce the following error.

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback did not match a registered redirect URI

Learn more

Request Details
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback
display=page
client_id=400798961688.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

My google console have the following url registered.

```
Redirect URIs:  
http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback
https://localhost:8888/oauth2callback

JavaScript origins: http://localhost:8888
https://localhost:8888
```

Can anyone help me?